# how to access image files in eclipse (servlet/html)

Tags: java, html, eclipse, servlets

[image]

my directory structure looks like this.
i want to apply an image present in the resources folder(or any other folder) to my servlet ..

the code:

```
out.println("<body background='/resources/a.jpg'>");
```

but this is not loading up the  image onto the webpage.
i have tried placing it in src ,,,and accessing it via

```
out.println("<body background='/a.jpg'>");
```

but still nothing works.am i doing something wrong here?
one more thing - the image works fine in other standalone webpages i create.
i have also tried placing it directly besides the class file..that doesnt work either.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>second</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ram</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pack.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>data</param-name>
      <param-value>a.jpg</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ram</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/run</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the resources folder is viewable to the end user. I would try a test image and see if you can view it in the browser e.g:

```
http://localhost/myimages/1.jpg
```

If the above displays then you know that it is correctly getting access to the image.

Comment: i mean page not found.

Comment: what can be the reason for this ?i.e the pic not viewable?

Comment: It would suggest that the eclipse browser may not have access to the folder where the images are stored. Looking at your screenshot try creating a folder in the webcontent folder called myimages and place the 1.jpg in that and see if you can access it via the browser. I think whats happening is that the way you are trying to access the image has to be relative to what the browser can see if that makes sense.

Comment: and i have to add it to the source folder list as well?

Comment: again page not found and image not displayed.gosh this is annoying

Comment: it all depends on what your doing with it. If you are just accessing the image with a browser i.e using it as a page background then no you wouldnt need it in the resources folder as well. You would place it in that folder if your doing something server side that the client never needs to see. Even for the server side you can still process the image even if its in the myimages folder on the server side. For example if you wanted to resize the image on the fly. Just remember that:

Comment: http://localhost/ will more than likely point to webcontent as it root so anything you place in this folder will be viewable by the client and can be access by the server should you so wish. anything that you don't want to be accessible to the client browser should either be placed outside of the webcontent folder or placed in the webcontent folder but with security set on the folder so that only the serverside has access to. This varies between windows and linux.

Comment: basically yes. one way to find out is place a file that your don't have anywhere else in the webcontent folder and then see if you can access it in your browser. Give the file an obscure name.

Comment: i see some light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/third/a.jpg..and this displayed the picture !!!
updating the code and running it

Comment: arghhhhhhhhh!!! zilch!!!!
out.println("<body background='/a.jpg'>");
this should work now , right ?now that the web browser is able to access the a.jpg in the webcontent folder! but sadly it doesn;t!!1

Comment: oooooooooooooooooooooooooooohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: turns out it is already pointing to WebContent..we do not have to use "/"..now this also works : out.println("<body background='ress/b.jpg'>");

Comment: Yes you should need to use the / at the beginning as it should know what your referring to and like you say your already mapping to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your resources folder to the list of source folders.

Right Click -> Build Path -> Use as source folder

If you don't, then Eclipse won't copy the folder into the output folder and you can't access them in the way you tried to do.

Comment: ohkaay.thanks for the info.will try it in a jiffy.
(its not updating right now)

Comment: naaah man..nothing working!
i added a new folder "resources" while building the project itself.
still the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "resources" folder is at classpath of your web application.

Comment: you can see my directory structure.tell me where to put it

Comment: i created a new resources package in src as well..that dint work either :(

Comment: Take me your web.xml file, please.

Comment: Try change the following
`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ram</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/run</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`
to `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ram</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`